# Flutter : Get Sum of values group by product

Tags: flutter

How can I get the sum of values group by productName?

Here's my class:

```dart
class ProductClass{
  String  productName;
  int  price;
  bool status;
  ProductClass(this.productName, this.price, this.status);
}

// Here's is the data:
  _getSumByProduct(){
    List<ProductClass> productClass = List();
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Cup', 5, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Cup', 5, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoons', 3, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Plate', 7, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoon', 2, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoons', 8, true));

   // Code to Get sum of values by productName
 
  }
```

The answer would be: 
Cup, 10 
Plate, 7 
Spoons, 13

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the list and keep track of the sums of the products in a map:

```dart
  _getSumByProduct(){
    List<ProductClass> productClass = List();
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Cup', 5, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Cup', 5, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoons', 3, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Plate', 7, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoon', 2, true));
    productClass.add(ProductClass('Spoons', 8, true));

    Map<String, int> sumMap = {};

    productClass.forEach((product) {
        if (sumMap.containsKey(product.productName)) {
            sumMap[product.productName] += product.price;
        } else {
            sumMap[product.productName] = product.price;
        }
    })
    
    return sumMap;
  }
```

You end up with a map from `productName` to sum of prices. So to get your desired result:

```
print("Cup, ${sumMap['Cup']}");
print("Plate, ${sumMap['Plate']}");
print("Spoons, ${sumMap['Spoons']}");
```